# c++ inheritance with access modifiers

Tags: c++

i have this code snippet

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class Polygon
    {
        public:
            int publicmemberPolygon;
        private:
            int privatememberPolygon;
        protected:
            int protectedmemberPolygon;
   };

    class Square : public Polygon
    {
    public:
        int Getter();
     };
    int Square::Getter()
    {
    return privatememberPolygon;
    }

    int main()
    {
    }
```

problem is, why is privatememberPolygon is inaccesbile? isnt it, when you have a dervied class, all of its members/functions are copied? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, when you derive publicly from a base class, only its `public` and `protected` members are accessible for the derived class. You can also read this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/basics-of-inheritance.html#faq-19.6).

See this example:

```
class Base
{

public:
    void setPrivate(int p) 
    {
        m_private = p;
    }

public:
    int m_public;
protected:
    int m_protected;
private:
    int m_private;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void f()
    {
        m_public = 0; // Can access public member of base class
        m_protected = 0; //Can access protected member of base class
        m_private = 0; //Compiler error- Can not access private member of base class
    }
};

int main() {

    Derived d;
    d.setPrivate(10); //m_private is still part of the derived class. Hence can call setPrivate
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: i dont get it, um, when we say inherit, all the members/functions of the base class is copied to the child class right?

Comment: or is it, only the public and protected members are "copied" to that new derived class automatically?

Comment: It depends on the access specifier.

Comment: if you are inheriting publicly then only public and protected members are accessible.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque i have 1 clarification, suppose we have base class ClassA and derived class ClassB, when we do this, class ClassB : public ClassA, does all members are "copied" to ClassB?

Comment: i think this might solve my confusion, is this correct, "only the accesible members are copied/inherited/whatever to the derived class", so if one is a private member of base class, then its not going to be copied/inherited/whatever to the derived class. correct me if im wrong

Comment: @user963499: The private member is still part derived class, i.e. it is inherited. But you can not access it from the derived class. I will edit my response to make it more clear.

Comment: @ShaikhFarooque: No, the access specifier when inheriting doesn't matter. You always get access to the public and protected parts. The thing that changes is how the outside can get them. If you inherit publicly, well, everything stays the same. If you inherit with `protected`, public base members become protected in your class and as such only available to derived classes. When inheriting privately, everything you get from the base class is only useably by you.

Answer (score 2):

Only the public and the protected data members are accessible in inheritance when your inheriting publicly.

Answer (score 2):

Members are not "copied" to the derived class.  The derived class contains a subobject of the base class, almost the same as if you have a member variable.

In fact, composition and non-public inheritance are often considered two paths to solve the same problem.

A trivial difference, with non-public inheritance, is that members of a base subobject don't have to be qualified by an object name to find them, they're part of this (unless you have diamond inheritance, yuck!).  With public inheritance, there's also an implicit conversion from a pointer or reference to the derived class into a pointer or member to the base class.

The bigger difference is that inheritance allows overriding virtual functions, while composition does not.

And `protected` members (and bases) are practically useless in the final analysis, since they inhibit composition without providing a real benefit the way that `virtual` does.  Sometimes they're used when virtual functions already make inheritance a necessity.